# Problemas de filtrado de búsqueda usando el plugin Chosen en Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5, laravel, plugin

Estoy haciendo un filtrado para búsqueda en laravel. Usando Scope. Estoy usando un `Select` para filtrar por provincias y otro para los meses del año.

Estoy usando el plugin de JQuery Chosen. Que aparte de darle una mejor estética a los `Select`, le incorpora un buscador.

El tema es que usando este plugin no me realiza la búsqueda. O sea, cuando le doy enter sobre input, no hace nada (dicho sea, no pasa los datos por la URL con GET)

Desactivando Chosen (sacando el selector de la clase del select) manda correctamente los datos por GET

```
<div class="margen">
<!-- BUSCADOR DE EVENTOS -->
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'front.search.eventos','method'=>'GET','class'=>'narvar-form']) !!}

<div class="input-group">
    {!! Form::text('nombre',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Buscar Evento Por Nombre...', 'aria-describedby'=>'search']) !!}
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="search">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">
        </span>
    </span>      
</div>
<button aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 5px;" data-target="#collapseExample" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
    Busqueda Avanzada
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="panel panel-default margen-top">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('provincia_id','Provincia:') !!}
                {!! Form::select('provincia_id',$provincias,null,['class'=>'form-control select-provincia','placeholder'=>'Provincia del evento...']) !!}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                {!! Form::label('meses_id','Mes:') !!}
                {!! Form::select('meses_id',$meses,null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Elija el mes del evento...']) !!}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
<!-- FIN DEL BUSCADOR -->


</div>
<!-- /.row -->
@section('js')
  <script>
    $('.select-provincia').chosen({
        width: "100%"
    });
  </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por alguna razon para que anduviera el select mejorado, tenia que colocar un submit, lo hice simplemente moficando un poco el primer input-group

```
<div class="input-group">
    {!! Form::text('nombre',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Buscar evento por Nombre...', 'aria-describedby'=>'search']) !!}
    <span class="input-group-btn" id="search">
        {!! Form::submit('Buscar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </span>      
</div>
```

ya luego no importa cuando select adhiera con chosen, anda bien

Answer (score 0):

Podrías compartir el HTML generado por blade específicamente de los 2 select? Tanto el que tiene chosen como el que no?